# KSQL says it expects existing topic to have 2 partitions (topic has 1),

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb, confluent-platform

I am facing below error when trying to create Stream in KSQL from an existing Kafka topic.

> io.confluent.ksql.exception.KafkaTopicExistsException: A Kafka topic with the name 'test-data' already exists, with different partition/replica configuration than required. KSQL expects 2 partitions (topic has 1), and 1 replication factor (topic has 1).

Is it mandatory to have 2 partitions for creating a stream in KSQL?

Comment: It is not required to have 2 partitions to create a stream - can you share the version of KSQL that you are using and the command that you ran to create the stream?

Comment: i have the same issue, even overwriting thte values on the values.yaml file of the helm chart, it does not work: configurationOverrides:
  "ksql.sink.partitions": "1"
  "ksql.sink.replicas": "3"

Comment: Can you show your create statement? KSQL seems to say it wants to partitions in the topic

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're running a command such as:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO (<some column defs>)
  WITH (
     partitions=<some-value>, <-- explicitly setting partition count
     kafka_topic='test-data', 
     value_format='<something>'
 );
```

Specifically, are you explicitly setting the `partition` count in the `WITH` clause?

Neither the `PARTITIONS` nor the `REPLICAS` properties need to be set in the `WITH` clause when creating a `TABLE` or `STREAM` over an existing topic.  These only need to be set when you wish ksqlDB to create a new topic for your data.  If they are set, they *must* match any existing topic.

These doc pages provide more information on this subject:

https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/create-a-stream/
https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/create-a-table/

If this explanation does not cover your error, then please provide more information. E.g. ksql version, statements used, details of existing topics in Kafka etc.